# How do I implement this animation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How do I make this transition animation? Whenever the user clicks on the icon it should expand and go the center and after 2 seconds it should disappear.

[image]

I tried using AnimatorContainer but whenever I expand the icon size, it is pushing all the other widget out of bounds.

Comment: use lottie animation this is the package :- https://pub.dev/packages/lottie

Comment: @JaiminRaval I'm tried using the lottie but I'm not able to figure out how to expand it and center it.

Comment: Please provide the tried code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hero widget to fly the the widget across pages.

Here's an example:

Let's assuming you want to move CircleAvatar. Wrap it with the Hero widget like this:

```dart
    InkWell(
      onTap: gotoNextpage,
      child: const Hero(
        tag: 'the-flying-widget', // <- You can use any string, just make sure to keep it the same on both pages
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Optional: Use `PageRouteBuilder` to show a fade animation while navigating to `Page2` for a smoother experience or else you can simply use `MaterialPageRoute`.

```dart
  void gotoNextpage() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (
          context,
          animation,
          secondaryAnimation,
        ) {
          return const Page2();
        },
        transitionsBuilder: (
          context,
          animation,
          secondaryAnimation,
          child,
        ) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      ),
    );
  }
```

On the next page say Page2,

- Use the same widget
- Pop the page after 2 seconds in `initState()`
- Wrap the page with `WillPopScope` or `PopScope` (*whichever is available as per your Flutter version*) and return false to prevent popping the page manually

```dart
    class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
      const Page2({super.key});
      
      @override
      State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
    }
    
    class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        });
      }
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'the-flying-widget',
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed solution. I have tried it and it works flawlessly.